# Confidence interval for the mean of a discrete distribution with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, distribution, confidence-interval

I have a negative binomial distribution and need to solve the 95% confidence interval of its mean. I am using MATLAB and this is a `probDist` object.

As it is not normal I guess I have to use bootstrapping but I have no idea of how to implement it. I tried the `bootci` function but it needs samples as input, not a distribution.

EDIT: This is the code I have (it doesn't work):

```
r = 2;
p = 0.5;
dist_x = makedist('NegativeBinomial', 'R', r, 'p', p)
bootfun = @(x) mean(x);
bootci(1000, bootfun, dist_x)
```

And the ouput is:

```
Error using bootstrp>bootEvalCommand
(line 288)
BOOTFUN must have at least one
non-scalar argument.
```

Comment: Please add your try in a [mcve]

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for... Change your `bootci(1000,boot fun,dust_x)` to something like... `bootci(1000,bootfun,dist_x.random(100,1))` If this is what you are thinking then I will post a better answer. I don't have a firm grasp on bootstrapping statistics, but am willing to read up on it to provide a better answer.

Comment: Are you sure dist_x.random(100,1) generates a sample? (don't have the right version to check it, couldn't find it with researches)

Comment: Thank you very much @BrianGoodwin I understand you want to generate n random samples from the distribution and go from there. If I do that then the mean won't necessarily be the same as the mean of the distribution and I'm afraid that may hurt the whole procedure, is that correct? Thanks again!!

Comment: @Maria: I am not sure that is correct. The distribution parameters (R and p) are all that define the PDF. I think that `dist_x.random()` will generate random points that if you were to do `>> hist(dist_x.random(1000,1))`, you would see the distribution that you define by `R` and `p` values. Therefore, the mean of `dis_x.random(100,1)` should be equal to the mean of the distribution as defined via `R` and `p`. Thoughts?